# Confusion analyzing blobs using contours

Tags: opencv

I want to analyze the blobs received using contours. However, I came across with a slight problems where is there any difference analyzing the blobs before and after using the following code?

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rects3.size(); i++) {
    Scalar color = Scalar(255,255,255);
    drawContours( drawing3, contours3, i, color, CV_FILLED, 8);
}
```

before using the above, there are only some boundaries line and after using the code we can see the white blobs. As attached are the example of it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @iiro, I don't know which one is the correct one. Should I use the code to draw the white blobs and then analyze each blobs or should I directly analyze the blobs without using the code as given. Does it makes any difference?

Comment: How do you want to analyze them? Try not to fill them with code and see how it looks:
drawContours( drawing3, contours3, i, color, 1, 8);

Comment: I want to iterate through the possible blobs and then analyze it (area, perimeter, etc). After using findContours and without using drawContours I got the first image. After using drawContours I got the second image. Does it mean every time I have to use drawContours before analyzing the blobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You want to iterate through the possible blobs and then analyze it (area, perimeter, etc).**

Your contours are in vector called rects3.

```
// iterating trough
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rects3.size(); i++) {
    // get the bounding box of one contour
    Rect rect = boundingRect(rects3[i]);

    //area
    double area = contourArea(rects3[i]);

    //perimiter
    double perimiter = arcLength(rects3[i], true);

}
```

see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html

Comment: So I don't need to use drawContours? it is just for displaying purposes? Is there any difference with and without using drawContours to analyze the blobs because the image shown is before and after use drawContours.

Comment: Yes, drawContours is just displaying purposes. Image is different after that because you draw on it. 

Try this one:
Mat newdrawing = drawing3;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rects3.size(); i++) {
    Scalar color = Scalar(255,255,255);
    drawContours( newdrawing , contours3, i, color, CV_FILLED, 8);
}

imshow("new", newdrawing );
imshow("old", drawing3);

Comment: Okay...Thanks @iiro for clarifying and the info.